# Is there anyway to disable formly validation when clicking on a button or link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I've run into a problem with angular-formly validations, I havea password input that is autofocused and has formly validation:

```
validators: {
    required: {
        expression: validations.required,
        message: translate.get('global.requiredField')
    },
    loginFailed: {
        expression: validations.serverValidationOnlyMessage,
        message: translate.get('signin.passwordSoftLock')
    }
},
```

The validations.required function is:

```
    return {
        required: function($viewValue) {
            if (!$viewValue) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
```

I have a "ForgotPassword" link that sits right below this input, unfortunately when I click the link, it doesn't register because the validation message pushes the link down, which causes a ‘miss’ of the link on the first click. The second click is successful.

```
            {
                key: 'password',
                name: 'password',
                type: 'fieldPasswordWithShowToggle',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.get('global.passwordLabel'),
                    labelSrOnly: true,
                    placeholder: translate.get('global.passwordPlaceholder'),
                    toggleText: {
                        show: translate.get('userInformation.showPasswordLabel'),
                        hide: translate.get('userInformation.hidePasswordLabel')
                    },
                    actionLinks: [{
                        text: translate.get('signin.forgotPasswordLabel'),
                        onClick: function() {
                            flowstack.use('forgotpassword').next();
                        }
                    }],
                    focus: formParameters.usernameIsKnown
                },
```

the HTML for the actionLink:

```
<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button"
            style="position:absolute;"
            class="btn btn-xs btn-link"
            ng-repeat="link in to.actionLinks"
            ng-click="link.onClick()">
            {{link.text}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you adding the forgotten password link using the `fields` variable or manually?

Comment: Its actually using custom actionLinks, I'll edit the main post